# Is it realistic to try to slice a large object in real time? (let's say ~1M tris)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh

So, that. I have an object with a mesh that could potentially be quite large, and I would like to be able to slice it with a plane, so that only the part of the mesh in one side of the plane remains.

Is it feasible to do that in real time? I realize that the answer necessarily depends on hardware, so a broad answer is ok. If so, how should I approach the problem?

Comment: you would need super good GPU... and possibly algorithm too... I would suggest the approach to be testing it with much lesser amount of object first (say 10K) and test its performance. If the hardware + algorithm is proven to be good in that level, then you might consider to increase the number of objects. If it is not, try to solve it with small number first (better hardware, better algorithm). If you cannot prove it in small number, you cannot do it for bigger number.

Comment: @Ian I've got a code that works for well for regular unity shapes (cubes, spheres, etc.) and simple shapes, but for large meshes loading time rises to about a minute - a time that's several orders of magnitude slower than the desired result. I just don't know if it's due to my particular approach or if the whole concept is flawed from the start.

Answer (score 0):

It is very fast to intersect triangle mesh with a plane. That is due checking point
side regarding given plane is simple. Just make dot product of a point and plane normal
and compare it to plane 'value'.
I assume that in result you want also triangles intersected with a plane, not only whole triangles on positive side.

I suppose you store mesh as list of points and list of triangles, where each triangle is represented with three point indices.

With that, algorithm is:

```
For each point calculate dot product with plane normal
For each point calculate plane side it belongs. Positive or negative side or exactly on the plane.
For each triangle count number of it's points for each side.
  If all points are on positive side or on plane then take whole triangle
  If all points are on negative side or on plane then do not take triangle
  If some points are on positive side and some on negative side, calculate
         intersection points between triangle edges and plane and create triangles in a way:
     One point on positive side. Result is one triangle.
     Two points on positive side. Result is quadrilliteral, or two triangles.
     Plane intersect triangle exactly on one point. Similar to first case.
```

All operations are simple and linear to number of points. With that whole algorithm should be fast. I think it should intersect 1M trias mesh under a second.